# Why does including a gem in Gemfile resolve a railtie issue, even though this same gem is already included in Gemfile.lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to wrap my head around why a problem I was struggling with is now magically resolved.

I am building a Rails app that uses Spotify OAuth (via the `rspotify` gem) and became stuck [on the exact issue described here](https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection/issues/12#issue-1016349995). After spinning my wheels, I finally came [across this comment](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify/issues/96#issuecomment-867953255), recommending that I explicitly add the `omniauth` gem to my `Gemfile`.

Now, this `omniauth` gem was already a dependency in `Gemfile.lock` for `omniauth-oauth2` specifically. As the [linked comment](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify/issues/96#issuecomment-867953255) recommends, I included `omniauth` in my Gemfile and now my problem is seemingly resolved, but I don't really know why.

- Why does including a gem in your `Gemfile` resolve a railtie issue in this case?
- If a gem is already installed as a dependency (according to `Gemfile.lock`) isn't that evidence that a given gem was installed? If, say, `gem_foo` is listed as a dependency in `Gemfile.lock` and I add `gem_foo` in `Gemfile` and then run Bundler, how does Rails interpret this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to how `gems` are loaded by bundler. `Bundler.require`  requires gems listed in `Gemfile` but does not require its dependecy. Its upto the library to require/load its dependency.

The mentioned issue happens when `omniauth` is not added explicitly to Gemfile, hence bundler does not require it.

But since `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection` assumes the `ominauth` is already required, it errors out when user only adds `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection` but does not add `omniauth` to Gemfile.

I have created a possible fix for the issue https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection/pull/13

UPDATE: The is fix has been merged in the gem repo.

Comment: Thanks @the_spectator, this answers my question and clears things up. And double thank you for providing the fix on the actual gem in question!